# Why is Kendo dropDownList undefined

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I want to populate a Kendo dropdownlist with data from a database.

That's what I call the "frwMantenimientoEmpresas.aspx / SelectProvincias" method.

My problem is that the value "undefined" after making the call, in the dropdownlist appears ...

```js
dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      serverFiltering: true,
      transport: {
          read: {
              beforeSend: function (req) {
                  //alert("");
              },
              async: false,
              url: "frwMantenimientoEmpresas.aspx/SelectProvincias",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
          }
      },
      schema: {
          model: {
              fields: {
                  UIDProvincia: { type: "int" },
                  Nombre: { type: "string" }

              }
          }
      }
});

$("#dropProv").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource:dataSource1,
    dataTextField: "Nombre",
    dataValueField: "UIDProvincia",
    autoBind: true,
});
```

The read method calls the server SelectProvincias method correctly..

At this point dropDownList = undefined??

Comment: It is already the problem was that I lack the attribute data -> data:"d"  of schema

Comment: Close the question, if you have got the answer